# the picture moves up and down the page. / SwiftUi

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created this code in VStack, the image is rotating and slowly moving up and down. How can I fix?

```
@State private var zRotateAnimation = false

ZStack {
    Spacer().frame(height:geometry.size.height / 13) // resim üst boşluk
    HStack {
        Image("HandP").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(zRotateAnimation ? 360 : 0))
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 50)
                        .repeatForever(autoreverses: true))
            .onAppear() {
                self.zRotateAnimation.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify where is the issue and what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what do you try to fix, but try the following

```
HStack {
    Image("HandP").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(zRotateAnimation ? 360 : 0))
        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 50)
                    .repeatForever(autoreverses: true), 
                    value: self.zRotateAnimation)       // << link to state
        .onAppear() {
            self.zRotateAnimation.toggle()
        }
}
```